# Prove h is differentiable and f is not differentiable at origin where $f(x,y)=\frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For 
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
               \frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \text{ for }(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
               0 \text{ for } (x,y)=(0,0)
            \end{cases}$$
Fix any $v\in\mathbb{R^2}$ with $||v||=1$ and define $h_v:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ via $h_v(t)=f(tv)$. I'm trying to prove that $h_v$ is differentiable and find $h'_v(0).$ Also, I'm trying to prove that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0).$

My plan is that using the definition of being differentiable, i.e., find
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{||h_v(t+h)-h_v(t)||}{||h||}.$$
However, the result I got is this limit is equal to $\frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ which seems wrong.
Here's how I did it,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{||h_v(t+h)-h_v(t)||}{||h||}=&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{||f((t+h)v)-f(tv)||}{||h||}\\
=&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{||f(tv)+f(hv)-f(tv)||}{||h||}\\
=&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{||f(hv)||}{||h||}\\
=&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{||h||}\\
=&\frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{align*}
Also, in order to show $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, I want to show $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0),$ but seems $f$ is continuous everywhere. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: there are many errors. hints: 1.) $h_v(t) = t v_1 |v_2|$. 2.) $h_v'(0)$ is not linear in $v$.

Comment: It should be $h_v(t) = f(t,v)$. And $f(t+h,v) \neq f(t,v) + f(h,v)$.

Comment: I get where I'm wrong. But what about prove $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable at $0$, $h_v'(0)$ needs to be linear in $v$. That is clearly not the case.